Python Calculations in a data frame
I have a dataframe in python that has many columns of baseball data. Every pitch is another row and specifically for this problem two of the columns are "Inning": which is the inning the pitch took place in, and "Outs": which is how many outs at the time of the pitch. I am trying to create a function that calculates Innings pitched for a pitcher which is calculated as follows. If a pitcher pitches 3 innings and gets taken out in the 4th while they got the first 2 outs, they will have pitched 3.2 innings. if they had pitched 1 out then it would be 3.1 outs. The data frame has multiple different games so I need to add up all the innings pitched in the different games (for example if game 1 they pitched 3.1 innings and game 2 was 4.2 innings this would be 8 innings pitched). This is the function I have right now:
def calc_innings_pitched(pitcher_df):
  innings_pitched = 0.0
  for date, game_df in pitcher_df.groupby('Date'):
    max_inning = game_df['Inning'].max()
    last_row = game_df.iloc[-1]
    outs = last_row['Outs']
    innings = max_inning + (outs / 3.0)
    innings_pitched += innings

  if innings_pitched % 1 == (1/3):
    return int(innings_pitched) + 0.1
  elif innings_pitched % 1 == (1/3):
    return int(innings_pitched) + 0.2
  else:
    return innings_pitched

Ive tried a couple of methods on my own and a couple of chat gpt generated answers but none can calculate it correctly.
I cant post the original data set but the Pitcher_df would look like this:



Date
Inning
Outs




6/6
1
0


6/6
1
1


6/6
1
2


6/6
2
0


6/6
2
1


6/6
2
2


6/6
3
0


6/6
3
1


6/6
3
2


6/6
4
0


6/6
4
1


6/7
1
0


6/7
1
1


6/7
1
2


6/7
2
0


6/7
2
1


6/7
2
1


6/7
2
2



This should give Innings Pitched value of 4.1 for the game on 6/6 and 2.2 for the game on 6/7. This would then add up to be 7 Innings pitched. I do not need the individual games to be formatted as 4.1 and 2.2 as opposed to 4.333 and 2.666 as I only need the total innings returned.

I just figured out that it should be unique innings instead of max innings because a reliever isnt guaranteed  to have pitched from inning 1 so I have that right now but I still have a couple too many innings in the calculation

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you print an example of a pitcher_df and paste it into your question, as well as both the actual and expected results of calling calc_innings_pitched() with that df? That will help us better answer your question. (Read [mre] for more info when you have time.)

I'd be careful treating these values as floating point numbers. For instance, does 3.9 have meaning in this context? The fact that, in this number system, 3.1 + 4.2 = 8.0 illustrates that they are not floats. These values are actually encoded strings.

Please add tags, are you asking about [tag:numpy] or [tag:pandas] or something else? Python itself does not have dataframes.

I do not know enough about Python or its terminology to correctly tag this. I believe this is simply an order of operations question and if I had the answer in a different programming language I could write it into Python myself. I would honestly be okay with the equation using math symbols as well. I just don't know how to calculate the statistic from a table

How do 4.1 and 2.2 add up to 7? Anyway, your calc_innings_pitched returns 7, so what's the issue? To illustrate it, you'd have to post data where your function doesn't return the desired result.

I'm using the example data you provided, so you may need to adapt this. But how I would do it:
Count the number of rows grouped by the date (drop any duplicates of Date, Inning, Out) and divide by 3 since theres 3 outs per inning. This will tell you how many innings the pitcher pitched.
Then take the sum of that output and multiple the decimal by 3/10 to convert .3333 (1/3) and .66667 (2/3) to .1 and .2.
import pandas as pd

# Create the data as a dictionary
data = {
    "Date": ["6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/6", "6/7", "6/7", "6/7", "6/7", "6/7", "6/7", "6/7"],
    "Inning": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "Outs": [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)



grouped_counts_divided = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Inning', 'Outs']).groupby('Date').size().div(3).reset_index(name='Count_Divided')
print(grouped_counts_divided)


# Sum the 'Count_Divided' values
total_count_divided = grouped_counts_divided['Count_Divided'].sum()
print(total_count_divided)

# Convert the sum to mod 3 format
mod3_value = round((total_count_divided - int(total_count_divided)) * 3)/10 + int(total_count_divided)
print(mod3_value)

Output:
  Date  Count_Divided
0  6/6       3.666667
1  6/7       2.000000
5.666666666666666
5.2

